# pam_ecryptfs: Error getting passwd (ProFTPD)

Tags: ubuntu, pam, ftp, ecryptfs

```
proftpd: pam_ecryptfs: Error getting passwd info for user [USERNAME]
```

I am getting this error in the syslog nearly every time any user connects via FTP, the user is able to connect and the session seems to continue without a hitch.
ProFTPD.log shows no error, this warning only show in the syslog.

My VPS is running Ubuntu 11.10 and Proftpd 1.3.4rc2 from the Ubuntu Repo, I have made only a few changes to the config (no weird auth methods). This has been going on for quite a while but I can't quite find the cause.

Anyone got any ideas?

EDIT: been looking around but all I can find with this error is the source code for the program itself; it appears to be and error in ecryptfs-utils that only proftpd is triggering.

Comment: Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only answer seems to be to ignore it and carry on.
For anyone else with the same issue here is a rule to hide the error from the logs

Add to /etc/rsyslog.conf (Or equiv)

```
:msg, contains, "Error getting passwd info for user" ~
```

Just ensure it is above any other rules (that might catch it)

Answer (score 1):

You might check the contents of your `/etc/pam.d/ftpd`, `/etc/pam.d/proftpd`, or `/etc/pam.conf` (or similar) files.  ProFTPD, by default, attempts to use PAM for authentication; the `pam_ecryptfs` part of the error message suggests it's a PAM module which is complaining.  The PAM configuration files should list that `pam_ecryptfs` module.

Another solution is to tell ProFTPD not to try to use PAM, via the following, in your `proftpd.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_auth_pam.c>
  AuthPAM off
</IfModule>
```